# Largest comeback against Bill Belichick Patriots

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

What is the largest deficit overcome against the New England Patriots in the Bill Belichick era? I have searched all over the Internet and cannot find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

To date, the [largest blown lead](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/blown_leads.htm) in the Belichick era came on September 25th, 2011 against the Bills in Buffalo. The Patriots led by 21 points in the second quarter and ultimately lost 34-31.

Answer (score -3):

It depends what you mean by the largest blown lead.    I watched the Buffalo game vs the Pats and the Pats were down 21 but Buffalo scored 10 before half and I don't think 21-10 comeback with momentum is an incredible comeback.    The Bills threw two quick INTs to start out the game but by the half they were down but there was no feeling the game was over.

To second that the Bills got a 7 point lead and basically played prevent D (watch the game) and let the Pats march down the field.   The Pats scored too quick and with the game tied, Bills easily got into FG range to win it.   It was more of a comeback by the Pats than the Bills.

Now the 2009 Colts game.   Holy crap the Patriots were up 17 in the 4th (and got a FG in the 4th) and Peyton Manning shredded them.   It was for sure the biggest comeback against a Belichek team in the current Pats era.   Belichek got so nervous going against Peyton that he crapped his pants and went for it on 4th and 2 in his own territory - around the 30 not even midfield.    It was a crazy game and the biggest comeback loss for him for sure.